# The “free” energy device is possible if you look like this?

Tags: energy, perpetual-motion

As I understood (please correct me if I am wrong)  all “free energy” devices, in the end, stuck on the “energy conservation” law so you can’t have more energy than you put into the system. But I think maybe if we live in the “real world” it is more an engineering problem than a physics problem and a “free” energy device is possible after all? 
Here is my thinking - let’s say we can create a device that somehow spins or do something else to generate electricity,  by conservation of energy it is not possible that this device will generate energy forever, however, we live in the real world and this device will wear off due to friction and material destruction so we need to fix it after some time. In order to fixit we need to have some matter and some energy to do so. So in infinite time scale, this device can’t run forever so it is not breaking conservation of energy, however, on the human or galactic time scale it will still be very useful to have such a device? Are all energy “generation” devices that we have are essentially doing the same thing? So am I right to assume that all these “free” energy devices (which are not so “free” and not so infinite after all) is still useful idea to pursue or am I missing something in my reasoning?

**UPDATE**
Not sure why people downvote the question but some comments and answers point out that maybe I didn't explained it correctly. 
I am NOT arguing that you can create absolutely free energy machine that you can "generate energy" out of nothing forever. I am just trying to understand if the fact that some potential machine that can generate energy out of "nothing" - some magnetic mambo jumbo wheel can, in principle, do that because due to the fact that it is operating in the real world and eventually will be subject to friction and another destruction so it will need some energy and matter to be fixed and because of that it doesn't violate the conservation of energy law so maybe it can be done so maybe it is worth pursuing such ideas because it is possible to do this and no laws are violated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking from what you've written.

Comment: @Charlie sorry for that, the question if my reasoning is right or wrong and if it is possible to create such device given that it does not violate the conservation of energy (if understood everything right).

Comment: If you have to put energy in, it's not free anymore

Comment: You can get enormous amounts of energy by converting matter to energy. Even the nuclear fusion of deuterium dissolved in one liter of ordinary water gives as much energy as burning 300 liters of gasoline. Imagine how much water is in the oceans. However, harvesting this energy would quickly overheat the planet. So getting practically free energy would be the worst possible invention leading to the extinction of the humankind.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Well, I have used quotation marks to emphasize that is not so free after all. I am not arguing that it is free on the infinite scale I am just assuming that those devices are, maybe, not so nonsensical.

Comment: @safesphere right, but there is a lot of space around?:)

Comment: For what would you use the energy in space?

Comment: @safesphere keep space station, mars base alive and etc. Move half of the people to mars so out planet feels bit better?

Comment: If we produce so many people that we must sentence some to a lifetime on Mars, then perhaps the problem is not energy in the first place, but overpopulation? And perhaps the solution is not sending people to Mars, but producing fewer of them?

Comment: @safesphere I believe StackExchange don't like these types of conversations here in comments. I agree with you completely but that was not the question, I am just playing around with physics in my head and don't want to conquer nor save the world:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are still trying to say, the device is simply not a free energy device then, all you've built is just a more complicated battery really, you'd have to put the energy in to charge it and you get less out than you put in.

Comment: I have used quotation marks regarding "free" part sorry if this is not how quotation marks are used in English it is not my first language. Battery is a good analogy but not quite thу same as you need to charge it before. I am thinking more about combustion engine but with delayed "payment" for a fuel, it doesn't mean you don't have to pay as in free devices people "inventing" where you have "energy from nothing". And I don't claim you can really build that device but want to understand how it doesn't work with conservation law.

Comment: @Triatticus actually I think battery example is really good but that depends of what to think of a battery of course, like atomic powerhouse is can be seen as well as a battery and so can be some mumbo jumbo magnetic device that you put atoms of device in certain way and it makes some work. And that goes to any energy device that we have because you can say that even the fuel is a part of "construction" of the device.

Comment: A battery is, or can be, anything that stores energy for later use. A free energy device is a device that gives you more energy than you input, even if things were frictionless you couldn't extract more energy than input into the system, thus no need to even try to justify why free energy devices don't exist due to real world wear and tear.

Comment: @blankblank "*StackExchange don't like these types of conversations*" - As you can see, StackExchange doesn't like these types of questions either. Energy simply is the rate of time: slower time (dilation) = less energy ($E=hf$). Unless you can make time move faster, there is no free energy.

Answer (score 2):

There are no free energy devices, even on a human time scale. In the real world, you would be skeptical about someone offering you free money. Physicists are like that about perpetual motion machines. There are good reasons to think they are impossible, and nobody has ever built a genuine one. Generally you don't even have to listen to details to know whatever is being proposed won't work.

You can get close to one kind of perpetual motion machine. For example, a pendulum swings back and forth. At each end it comes to a momentary stop. For a while, it can appear that it perfectly repeats. But if you watch longer, you will see that it is swinging slower and stopping at a lower place.

There are good reasons to say that no matter how you make a pendulum or spinning top or anything else, it must have some loss. It will eventually slow down. Unfortunately, the reasons are hard to explain.

I can only say that entropy always increases. What this means is energy can change from one kind to another. You can't create it out of nothing. Whenever anything moves, it has kinetic energy, energy of motion. There is always friction that turns some of it to heat. You can't turn this heat back into motion without adding more energy.

Of course you can add a little motor, and then it will run as long as the motor does. That is perfectly reasonable, but it isn't a perpetual motion machine. Motors need gas or electricity to run. You are putting more energy in all the time. This isn't free energy.

There is another kind of perpetual motion machine that produces more energy than it takes in. Something like a pendulum that starts out swinging just a little, but gets bigger and bigger swings, with no motor involved. This kinds is also impossible, and you can't even get close to it.

This is easier to explain. This kind of machine violates the law of conservation of energy. You can't make energy out of nothing.

These are what people mean by perpetual motion being impossible. It isn't that you could make one if only it didn't wear out. It isn't possible even while running well and still new.

Comment: Mm, maybe my english is not good enough so I have not explained right in my question. But what (as I understand) you are explaining is just why these machines would not work because of conservation of energy which is not my point. I am just assuming that if this machine is in the real world around as, the fact that this machine can't run forever without any damage due to friction and other factors can say that in principle this machine can be made but due to it's fragility after some time you need to put matter or energy to fix it (change oil, change parts) so there is no energy from nothing

Comment: Yes, I spent most of the answer saying that such machines are not possible at all. Hopefully the last two lines answered your question. Damage due to friction or wear, fragility, and things like this are not the reason such machines are impossible.

Comment: I am sorry you got slammed so hard for this question. It just reflects the attitude of physicists toward perpetual motion machines. Usually such machines are proposed by frauds or people with little understanding. Therefore no question about them can be sensible. This was not a bad question.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I understand why such topics are sensitive but I don't believe they are not worth discussing and I wasn't even tried to prove that anything of the current physics is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The law of energy conservation means that energy *cannot* be created or destroyed. You can't get around that law merely by saying your device will wear out in the real world.

Here's a crude analogy. If I give you a 10 litre bucket full of water, you may get less than the whole 10 litres from it, due to evaporation, spills, leaks, etc. But there's no way for you to get *more* than 10 litres of water out of that bucket, without refilling it somehow.

> Let’s say we can create a device that somehow spins or does something else to generate electricity.

We could easily make a disc spin in space for a *very* long time. But if you generate electricity from that spinning motion then the spinning will slow down and stop, as you convert the spinning energy of the disc into electricity. Just like the water in the bucket, you can't get more energy out of the disc than what you stored there by spinning it in the first place.

Comment: Again maybe I explained it wrong. I am NOT claiming that you can CREATE energy out of nothing. I am claiming that the fact that this device is in the real world and eventually wear that exact thing means that it doesn't violate the conservation of energy law because you need to fix it and for that, you need energy and matter and this device will still increase entropy after all.

Comment: @blankblank But that's like saying a car can't run forever on a single tank of fuel because eventually it will need an oil change. Yes, it's true that it'll need an oil change, but that is *not* the reason why it won't run forever on a single tank.

Comment: well in case of a car it surely can't but that doesn't mean that some other device can't? I am trying to understand how it correlates with a law of conservation. Correct me if I am wrong now please - am I right that this law says that you can't have MORE energy out than you put in the system? If so that is the thing that I am claiming - you do not put less energy in the system, you just put it in the form of construction of that system, eventually when it wears off you repeat, and when all matter and energy spent then it is over yes.

Comment: also one more idea to consider - you can think of car fuel as a part of the construction but that needs to be fixed early, or you can take an atomic powerplant and have even more energy and it needs to be fixed much less, so if we go further we can come to better construction = more energy or less malfunction until we got to conservation law. Is that mean we can actually create virtually any device given other laws of physics including where is fuel=construction?

Comment: @blankblank The law does not says that the amount of energy taken must be less than put in. It says, that the energy contained in isolated system is same at all times. Consider system composed of fuel, machine and you. The machine contains energy $E_1$, you contain energy $E_2$ and fuel contains energy $E_3$. The law tells you that $E_1+E_2+E_2$ is always the same. When you take only conservation of energy into an account, you can reshuffle the energy in whatever way you want, but the overall energy must be the same. ou cannot borrow from the future -  as it seems to me that you are (cont.)

Comment: ...suggesting, it must be the same at every point in time. You can create machine that takes all the fuel and gives you more energy than the energy in the fuel. But this energy had to be taken from somewhere and in this case it had to be taken from the machines own energy $E_1$. So you used machine as kind of a battery - you just took energy stored inside it. But you can never take more than $E_1+E_3,$  because there is simply no that much of energy contained in fuel and machine together.

Comment: @blankblank I think your main difficulty is in your wrong definition "you can't have MORE energy out than you put in the system" which would suggest that all the energy taken must be zero or less over the whole time. so you think about taking more energy now and returning it back later. This is not the case. The energy conservation, as i told you, must be obeyed at every instance and the energy that must be conserved is energy contained in the whole isolated system. If you take as system only machine and fuel, then it is not isolated and law does not apply for this system,.

Comment: @Umaxo thank you very much for clarification, yes that is indeed what I was talking about and I think main confusion goes not from me but from people who doesn't understand the question (either because they don't want or I chose wrong words to do that) - basically that what I was talking about - the construction of machine has some energy in it and you put it in by "fixing" it so this all should work then. Like for example some robot that takes part of itself, then make atom,ic reaction with that and give you some energy - you still need to give some uranium part for that robot.

Comment: @Umaxo And one step forward is that if that's all hold out, then in principle there is huge amount of machines that can be made that can extract energy out of it's construction in different ways be it magnetic wheels or anything because you still need to put energy in in the form of keeping construction intact. Let me please know if I am still missing something here?

Comment: @Umaxo and yes maybe that I have used words "from the future" about paying for energy that can be misleading but that is a bad use of words.

Comment: @blankblank I think the comments by Triatticus, especially [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538475/the-free-energy-device-is-possible-if-you-look-like-this/538512?noredirect=1#comment1219173_538475) about batteries vs "free energy" gets to the heart of your question. But it isn't easy to understand your English! Some people voted to close your question because it's unclear, and some people voted to close it for being "non-mainstream" because it seems to them that you are claiming that "free energy" devices are possible.

Comment: @PM 2Ring noted, will try to improve my language:) As I mentioned above and by answering to Triatticus as well I agree that this is a close analogy, yet this argument is more in favor of what I am asking and not against that? Again I might be wrong all around, I am okay with that, I am not dogmatic and just want to understand the world better.

Comment: @PM 2Ring and basically in the end it still looks like if you look at construction of the machine as a battery then it is totally possible to make any device that will generate energy (even mumbo-jumbo magnetic nonsense), at least in principle but still obey all laws of physics, am I still missing something with that reasoning?

Comment: @blankblank Yes, that's basically correct, but it would be more accurate to say that the device *releases* energy, or that it converts energy from one form to another. In common language we may talk about generating energy, but in physics we should be more careful with the terminology. ;)

Comment: @PM 2Ring fair point:) Totally agree with that but I am not a physicist nor native English speaker so that definitely adds to the problem for sure. Thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is wrong.

The devices advertised as free energy generators are not real just because they wear out and have to be fixed or contain friction and therefore run down and stop- they are not real because *there is no free energy to be harvested in the first place*.

The concept of *energy conservation* is a mathematical way of saying that (for example) you cannot withdraw more money from your savings account than it contained to begin with. This means that if anyone claims that they can pull "free energy" out of nothing, their claim is identical to the claim that they could pull more money out of their bank account than they deposited in it a minute before, in the sense that both claims are *fraudulent*.

Comment: Well as I see my reasoning is same as yours (please forgive me if my initial question not make it clear) - the machine will eventually break, so you need to put some matter (change oil) and energy (person who will change it) so it can continue to operate. What i am saying that the fact that you need to do that says that in principle we can do such a machine that will generate us energy for thousands of years because it doesn't violate the law of conservation (because you HAVE to fix it in the end).

Comment: still wrong. do you know about the laws of thermodynamics?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can explain to me what is still wrong. (but just to be clear again I am NOT saying that you can create the machine that will generate free energy forever, nor am I saying that it will not increase entropy).